# How can I scrape websites?

Tags: java, android

I know how to parse RSS feeds, but how can one read the articles ? Do I have to scrape the website? Or is there an alternative for parsing the article in java?

Thanks in advance

Edit:
I decided to use [jSoup](http://jsoup.org).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the RSS feed (presumably) contains URLs that are the links to the articles, so it (presumably) boils down to what you mean by "read".

- If you simply need to fetch them, then use `URL.getInputStream` or some other HTTP client library.
- If you want to display the news article pages for the end user to read, then you just need to open the URL in the native browser.
- If you want to extract the article text, then yes you do need to parse the HTML either using a proper HTML parser or (blech!) using kludgey text pattern recognition that ignores the HTML structure.